# How to order points on a road linestring to follow the road

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, java, osm2pgsql

So I'm using a osm2pgsql schema. When I get a road, the points in the linestring don't have an order, so when I try to draw the road, it won't follow the road but will be a bunch of lines. Do I have to do the ordering myself? If so hhow? How do I order the points so they follow the road.

Comment: Please tell more about your usecase. AFAIK the order of linesegments isn't important for rendering?

Answer (score 1):

If by road, you mean an OpenStreetMap way, the coordinates in the linestring are ordered.

If by road, you mean something else, the answer is, it depends. For many purposes like rendering, the order doesn't matter.  If you need to merge multiple linestrings, the technique is called [glomming](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shp-to-osm.jar#Glomming) and would need to be done with [PostGIS functions](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/).